# Getting Error "could not find function "assign<-" inside of colnames()

Tags: r, runtime-error

I'm using assign() to assign some new data frames from some other data frame. I then want to name some of the columns in the new data frame. When I use assign() to create the new data frames it works fine. But when I use the assign() inside of colnames() is gives the error 'Error "could not find function "assign<-".'

Here's my snippet of code(abbreviated of course):

```
    for(i in 1:value) {       
        assign(Name[i], Old.Data.Frame[Old.Data.Frame$1 == Index[i]]) #I'm going to call this line of code 'New Data Frame' for brevity
        for(j in 1:ncol(New Data Frame)) {
            colnames(New Data Frame)[j] = as.character(Old.Data.Frame[3,j])
```

I do all this assign() stuff because the names of the Old Data Frame constantly change and I can create any concrete variables in my code, only the dimentions of the frame stay the same.

The only error in this code is that R cannot "find function assign<- in colnames(...". I'm flustered because assign() had just worked in the line before, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @G5W I think the OP has simply written `New Data Frame` in place of the entire `assign` line.

Comment: This looks like a classic "I've coded myself into a corner by using a terrible tool: `assign`", but I can't really tell enough of the bigger picture to be much help in refactoring this to avoid using `assign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of variable names in `Name`, which you assign a value (your code block).

```
for(i in 1:value) { assign(Name[i], Old.Data.Frame[Old.Data.Frame$1 == Index[i]]) }
```

Could you then try (note I'm separating this code block for debugging purposes):

```
for(i in 1:value) { colnames(get(Names[i])) <- as.character(Old.Data.Frame[3,] }
```

`get` will retrieve the data (data.frame) assigned to the variable name `Names[i]` (character)